# Issue with PHP header function in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

After a successful login (i.e when user clicks the login button after entering the username and password), based on the user type I want to send user to a specific page. Below is my code. (Here, if usertype is 'employee', he should be taken to "data-update.php" page after clicking 'login' button.)

This is the code in the index.php page:

```
// This file is the home page.

// Require the configuration before any PHP code as the configuration controls error reporting:
require ('config.inc.php');

// The config file also starts the session.

// Require the database connection:
require (MYSQL);

// If it's a POST request, handle the login attempt:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include ('login.inc.php');
}

/* PAGE CONTENT STARTS HERE! */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

This is the code in the login.inc.php page:

```
<?php 

// This is the login page for the site.
// It's included by index.php, which receives the login form data.

// Array for recording errors:
$login_errors = array();

// Validate the username:


// Validate the password:


if (empty($login_errors)) { // OK to proceed!

// Query the database:
$q = "SELECT id, type FROM users WHERE (username='$u' AND pass='"  .  get_password_hash($p) .  "')";        
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made.

    // Get the data:
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM); 

    // Store the data in a session:
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[0];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $u;     

    if ($row[1] == 'employee') {
        reset_sms_update_session();
        header("Location: http://".BASE_URL."data-update.php");                         
        exit;
    }
    elseif ($row[1] == 'client'){
        header("Location: http://".BASE_URL."About.html");
        exit;
    }

...
```

And this is a partial code in "data-update.php" page:

```
 // Start the session:
 session_start();

function redirect_invalid_user($check = 'user_id', $destination = 'index.php', $protocol = 'http://') {

// Check for the session item:
if (!isset($_SESSION[$check])) {
    $url = $protocol . BASE_URL . $destination; // Define the URL.
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script.
}

} // End of redirect_invalid_user() function.

//Redirect to index.php if user not logged in
redirect_invalid_user( );

/* PAGE CONTENT STARTS HERE! */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

...
```

The problem is that, in Google Chrome when user clicks the login button, he is first taken to the index.php page (where the redirection occurs) and then he has to click login button again to be taken to "data-update.php" page.
Why is this happening in Google Chrome?
(FYI: this does not happen in XAMP testing environment in my local PC.)

This does NOT happen in Firefox or IE8 (i.e. user is taken to "data-update.php" first time login button is clicked).

Please help.

Comment: Is `index.php` the login page? It might also be that FF takes the user to `index.php` and then to the actual page but it might be happening so quickly that you're not able to notice it

Comment: Yes, the login code is in the index.php page.

Comment: Do you send the header after sending content?

Comment: No, the redirection code is before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my HTML5 page. Additionally, though I am using `include ('login.inc.php');`, login.inc.php does not have the closing php tag.

Comment: asprin: to clarify, when I go to the site, the url is `www.site.com`. When I click the login button the first time, the url becomes: `www.site.com/index.php`. When i click the login button a second time, the url becomes `www.site.com/data-update.php`

Comment: We will need to see more of your login+redirection code to see what might be wrong

Comment: As requested, I have provided more code for further insight.

Comment: After some research, I found this: http://stuporglue.org/chrome-not-redirecting-with-php-headerlocation-redirect/, where it says to use `session_write_close();` but even that is not making any difference in my case. Someone please help!

Comment: Is there any whitespace after the closing ?> tag in any of your php files?

Comment: Where ever possible, i have actually omitted the closing tag. Please note that this is happening only in Chrome.

Comment: I have actually been able to identify what is happening here. When I go to the site using `http://example.com` and then click on login button, the page url changes to `http://www.example.com/index.php`. On a second click of the login button, I am taken to `data-update.php` page. However, if I go to the site using `http://www.example.com`, I am taken to the `data-update.php` page on the first click of the login button. So, someone please tell me how do prevent changing the url to `http://www.example.com/index.php` when I reach the site via `http://example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting a permanent redirect from CPanel in my webserver for `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`.